# Is there a way to get ID of the starting URL from database in scrapy with some function, make_requests_from_url

Tags: scrapy

I am pulling start URL's from Database and also need ID's associated with the URL so that I can pass it in the ITEMS pipeline and store in the table along with items.

I am using "make_requests_from_url(row[1])" to pass the start URL's "start_urls = []" which forms the list of starting URL's. The id's row[0] is what I need to pass to Items when the respective items are crawled.

Below is my spider code:

```
import scrapy
import mysql.connector
from ..items import AmzProductinfoItem


class AmzProductinfoSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amz_ProductInfo_Spider'
    nextPageNumber = 2
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.in']
    start_urls = []
    url_fid = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='datacollecter', user='root', password='', charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def start_requests(self):

        sql_get_StartUrl = 'SELECT * FROM database.table'
        self.cursor.execute(sql_get_StartUrl)
        rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(row[1])
```

I have tried with comparing "response.url" in parse method but that changes as spider moves on to next page.

Not sure how can I achieve this. any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why do you need `self.make_requests_from_url`. You can `yield` your requests directly:

```
def start_requests(self):

    sql_get_StartUrl = 'SELECT * FROM database.table'
    self.cursor.execute(sql_get_StartUrl)
    rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=row[1], meta={'url_id': row[0]}, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    url_id = response.meta["url_id"]
```

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I was unaware that I could yield request directly to parse method and understood that "self.make_requests_from_url" was the way to populate the start_urls.
I would try your suggestion which now completely makes sense for what I have to implement and update my comment. Seems I also have to rigorously go through python and scrapy documentation.

Comment: This works perfectly well as suggested. I am accepting this as the answer. Thanks